# I have written this code but it does output the value associated with sam key value pair? please tell me how to get the value of sam?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] argh) {
  Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = in.nextInt();
  String name = "sam";
  int phone = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    name = in.next();
    phone = in.nextInt();
    myMap.put(name, phone);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
      String s = in.next();
      if (myMap.containsKey(s)) {
        System.out.println(name + "=" + phone);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Not found");
      }
    }
    in.close();
  }
}
```

I have written this code but it does output the value associated with sam key value pair?

please tell me how to get the value of sam?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: 3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry

Comment: You need to use `s + "=" + myMap.get(s)` to print the phone number associated with `s`, not `name+"="+ phone`.

Comment: but s is the name string how do i get the number

Comment: Why do you enter several name-phone-pairs although your code obviously searches for the name right after entering the first pair?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
    if(myMap.containsKey(s)){
        System.out.println(name+"="+ phone );
    }
```

You're checking if the map contains the `s` key, and then printing whatever is in the `name` and `phone` variables.

Instead, actually get the phone number associated with `s`:

```
    if(myMap.containsKey(s)){
        System.out.println(s+"="+ myMap.get(s) );
    }
```

Comment: thanks i got it thats why it always shows harry as output